# Cleaner or easier way to write this?

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I'm scrapping from here: https://www.usatoday.com/sports/ncaaf/sagarin/ and the page is just a mess of font tags.  I've been able to successfully scrape the data that I need, but I'm curious if I could written this 'cleaner' I guess for lack of a better word.  It just seems silly that I have to use three different temporary lists as I stage the cleanup of the scrapped data.

For example, here is my snippet of code that gets the overall rating for each team in the "table" on that page:

```
source = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.usatoday.com/sports/ncaaf/sagarin/').read()
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(source, "lxml")
page_source = soup.find("font", {"color": "#000000"}

sagarin_raw_rating_list = page_source.find_all("font", {"color": "#9900ff"})
raw_ratings = sagarin_raw_rating_list[:-1]
temp_list = [element.text for element in raw_ratings]
temp_list_cleanup1 = [element for element in temp_list if element != 'RATING']
temp_list_cleanup2 = re.findall("&nbsp\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)", str(temp_list_cleanup1))  
final_ratings_list = [element for element in temp_list_cleanup2 if element != home_team_advantage] # This variable is scrapped from another piece of code 
print(final_ratings_list)
```

This is for a private program for me and some friends so I'm the only one ever maintaining it, but it just seems a bit convoluted.  Part of the problem is the site because I have to do so much work to extract the relevant data.

Comment: `temp_list = [element.text for element in raw_ratings if element.text != 'RATING']`would at least consolidate two list comps. Beyond that, I'm not sure.

Comment: @roganjosh Ahh you are right on that one.  I'll do that and at least get rid of one list!  Thanks!

Comment: The data on that page is recursive....  Ouch.

Comment: @StephenRauch Yeah, its a real mess of a page.  Looks like it has been just 'pasted' into the document with no thought to structure.  I wrote another small scrapping program using espn.com and it was a beautiful site to work with.  Everything is done by template and in order.

Comment: this might be a good candidate for codereview.SE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main thing I see is that you turn `temp_list_cleanup1` into a string kind of unnecessarily. I don't think there's going to be that much of a difference between `re.findall` on one giant string and `re.search` on a bunch of smaller strings. After that you can swap out most of the list comprehensions `[...]` for generator comprehensions `(...)`. It doesn't eliminate any lines of code, but you don't store extra lists that you won't ever need again

```
temp_iter = (element.text for element in raw_ratings)
temp_iter_cleanup1 = (element for element in temp_iter if element != 'RATING')
# search each element individually, rather than one large string
temp_iter_cleanup2 = (re.search("&nbsp\s*(-?\d+\.\d+)", element).group(1)
                      for element in temp_iter_cleanup1)
# here do a list comprehension so that you have the scrubbed data stored
final_ratings_list = [element for element in temp_iter_cleanup2 if element != home_team_advantage]
```

Comment: As per my comment on the question, you can also reduce two comprehensions to one.

Comment: This is basically as good as I can figure it would get and it still looks messy.  I guess we can blame that on a crappy page that there is nothing I can do about.  Thanks for this!